# List processes that use the smart card readers

Tags: windows, winapi, process, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I'm writing a Windows service that must handle Smart card readers.

Very often, when I try to connect to an inserted Smart card, `SCardConnect()` fails with `SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION` which basically means:

> The smart card cannot be accessed because of other outstanding connections.

Fair enough.

I guess that a least one other process tries to access the Smart at the same time. But is there a way to determine which process(es) it is ?

Comment: We have noticed this problem on HP machines running HP Protect Tools and haven't been able to work around it yet (short of un-installing hp protect tools) - are you using an HP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your place I would try with the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to look at the file handles opened by *your application* if you access to the Smart card readers. To do this you should select your process and press <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> (menu "View"/"Low Pane View"/"Handes"). After you know the device name of the Smart card readers you will be able to find out *other processes which use the device* if you receive `SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION` error. You should just use <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> (menu "Find"/"Find Handle or DLL...") to find file handle.

Comment: @ereOn, Where you able to find which handle it is?

Comment: @Abatonime: Could you formulate your question more clear? What problem you have? Which kind of opened resources (handles) you need to localed?

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP. I followed your instructions but I could not find the handle in Process Explorer. I am asking OP if he was able to find it.